# how to solve Deep linking launching app 2 times?

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, deeplink

When I am clicking on my deep link 
it's opening my app in the current app but after it opens; it's again launching my app and opening default activity.

**manifest**

```
 <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="example.com" />
                <data android:host="www.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
 Intent intent = getIntent();
                Uri data = intent.getData();
                String uriString = data.toString();
                if (uriString.contains("index")) {
                    Intent a = new Intent( logActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    a.putExtra("url", uriString);
                    startActivity(a);
                    finish();
                }else{
if (uriString.contains("profile")) {

                    Intent a = new Intent( logActivity.this, profileActivity.class);
                    a.putExtra("url", uriString);
                    startActivity(a);
                    finish();
                }
}
}
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**this activity is working as expected:**
[image: this activity opened by deep link correctly]

**but this activity opening automatically(this is default app launch)**
[image: i don't know why launching app automatically]

Comment: Please share Java/kotlin code where you programmatically handled deeplink url.

Comment: please check question again .... @Ved

Comment: i got the issue actually this because of my mistake...

Comment: @SnehaJoshi; you can answer your own question too, if you found the issue and if it is working. It might help future readers.

Comment: Please share what mistake you were doing?

Comment: Please share what mistake you were doing?